# How i can access gmail inbox from ruby? Is there any api for that?

Tags: ruby, json, gmail

I want to access gmail api to access gmail inbox to read the messages. Is there any api so that i can access the inbox and parse the messages.

Right now in our project we are using `mailinatorpro` account and to access the account we are using

```
https://api.mailinatorpro.com/api/inbox?to=#{username}&access_token=#{self.access_token}"
```

and then we use JSON to parse the inbox. But now we are moving to gmail so is there any way to access the inbox?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
gem install ruby-gmail
```

[github ref](https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail)

Comment: Hi Sagar, thanx for you quick reply. I will try it. But is it the only way to solve the problem?

Comment: I used ruby-gmail, the issue i am facing is that, while i am running my cucumber scenarios, this gem is not able to connect to my gmail account also not able to fetch the mail body. But when i am trying to create one test.rb file and run from there i am able to connect with gmail and fetch the body as well. I have debugged it but couldn't get the solution. Please suggest solution if any.

Answer (score 1):

The `google-drive` gem uses the following syntax to access google drive:

```
GoogleDrive.login("username", "password")
```

but as you can see [here](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/blob/master/lib/google_drive/session.rb), the author has done a lot of work to make that syntax so simple.  This gem also allows you to login using oAuth, so that's an option also.  I would dig into that git repo for some examples if you're interested in making something a bit more custom - otherwise, [sagar junnarkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1337996/sagar-junnarkar)'s suggestion of using the `ruby-gmail` gem is a good one.

Comment: Thnx dax for your suggestion. I will try sagar's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a look at this gem I just built that use Gmail API and not using IMAP and SMTP:

```
gem install gmail-api-ruby
```

[gmail-api-ruby](https://github.com/jhk753/gmail-ruby-api)

Let me know what you think. We were not satisfied with ruby-gmail gem going through IMAP protocol